# Open devtools of a webview inside another webview in electron?

Tags: webview, electron, devtools

I develop a tool with electron. There are two webview components in the app. One shows the html page, another one shows the chrome devtools which debug the page. The current solution is:

```
const browserContents = browserView.getWebContents()
const devtoolsContents = devtoolsView.getWebContents()

browserContents.setDevToolsWebContents(devtoolsContents)
browserContents.debugger.attach();

browserContents.openDevTools({
     detach: true
})

browserContents.debugger.sendCommand(    // not work
          'Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled', 
  {
    enabled: true,
    configuration: 'mobile',
  }, function(err){
     if(err){console.log("Emulation err:", err);}
  }
);
```

The code above can solve the problem, but the `setTouchEmulationEnabled` does not work. So, I want to ask if there are any good ideas about how to solve this question?

Comment: this may help https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentssetdevtoolswebcontentsdevtoolswebcontents

Comment: Actually, you mention is what i had done. but the problem is that browserContents.debugger.sendCommand could't work if i open DevTools of the page webview。 I know a method to open a devtools of webview by using chrome-devtools scheme can solve this problem, but i don't know how the devtools connect to the page  webview.

Comment: You might find the answer that you've been waiting for here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990622/13057660

Answer (score 0):

```js
<webview-1>.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    require("electron").remote.webContents.fromId(<webview-1>.getWebContentsId()).setDevToolsWebContents(remote.webContents.fromId(<webview-2>.getWebContentsId()));
});
```