# How to open developer tools inside of a webview

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, chromium

I'm developing a browser using *Electron*. I've been trying to open the *developer tools* of a `webview`, and I did it using that code:

```
document.getElementById("MyWebView").openDevTools();
```

But the problem is that the *developer tools*' window is opened as a pop-up window (another window):
[image]

I want to know who can I open it side by side to the `webview` (by creating another `webview` that shows the *developer tools* or by some other ways...).
**For example**, here's a photo of *Baker Browser* (*Braker Browser* is a browser that is developed using *Electron*):
[image]

Here's some info about the current version of *Electron* that I'm using:

```
Electron version: 8.2.0
Chromium version: 80.0.3987.158
NodeJS version: 12.13.0
```

If there's some missing info that you need to have in order to help me, please ask for it. Thank you for helping in advance!

*Edit:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually turned out to be easy:

```
const wv = document.getElementById("MyWebView");
wv.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
  const devtoolsView = document.getElementById('DevTools');
  const browser = wv.getWebContents();
  browser.setDevToolsWebContents(devtoolsView.getWebContents());
  browser.openDevTools();
});
```

Comment: The above snippet worked, added a devtools into another webview tag. But it's as if the devtools view is not "inspecting" the webpage. It's Elements tab is blank

Answer (score 0):

Click the hamburger menu icon at the top right of devtools. The "Dock side" item at the top of that menu should allow you to choose where you want the tools.

But under some circumstances Chromium doesn't have enough control over the browser window to place the devtools in it. You may be hitting that problem with your embedded Electron view.

[image]

Comment: There's not such a thing as the *Dock side* option in the window that opens. Reload the page and check the last image.