# Electron : Enable HTTPS Requests from Webview Loaded Webpage

Tags: webview, electron, svelte

I could really use some help here. I've got this Electron Svelte app that loads a webpage in fullscreen using a webview component. But here's the thing: I need to make the HTTPS requests from the loaded webpage show up in the network tab. It's a specific feature I'm trying to get working, and I'm a bit stuck.

If anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Ive tried tweaking the web preferences such as webSecurity and ignore certificate errors but nothings seemed to work

Comment: Welcome ! By "network tab" are you refering to the dev tools ? If that the case you should look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989426/how-to-open-developer-tools-inside-of-a-webview

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’ll give that a go and try my luck, yeah I’m talking about the dev tools of the electron app don’t show the web view https requests basically to summarise I have a website that plays a loading screen and when all the videos of the website are loaded it then hides the loading screen, the feature works fine on chrome but on electron it doesn’t detect if the videos https requests are downloaded and it just hides the loading screen immediately